# It shows error while generating of entities using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This is my `EmployeeDetailEntity.java` class. in which i have used `@OnetoOne` annotation to make relationship with other entity named as `GenderEntity`. the following is my `EmployeeDetailEntity`

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="GenderEntity",referencedColumnName="id")
private GenderEntity gen;
```

This is my `GenderEntity.java` class in which i mapped out relationship with `EmployeedetailEntity.java` (`ReferencedById="id"`) where id is primary key.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="gen",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private EmployeeDetailEntity empdtl;
```

While generating Tables from Entities i get error (Generation failed See the console for more information) and my console is as follow:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [GENDERENTITY] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entities.PatientTypeEntity --> [DatabaseTable(PATIENTTYPEENTITY)])

Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [SHOPPROFILEENTITY] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entities.EmployeeDetailEntity --> [DatabaseTable(EMPLOYEEDETAILENTITY)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entities.PatientTypeEntity --> [DatabaseTable(PATIENTTYPEENTITY)])

Exception [EclipseLink-41] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: A non-read-only mapping must be defined for the sequence number field.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entities.EmployeeDetailEntity --> [DatabaseTable(EMPLOYEEDETAILENTITY)])
```

Descriptor Exceptions:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-93] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The table [GENDERENTITY] is not present in this descriptor.
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(entities.PatientTypeEntity --> [DatabaseTable(PATIENTTYPEENTITY)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in below line:

```
@JoinColumn(name="GenderEntity",referencedColumnName="id")
```

Do as below:

The interesting part is the `@JoinColumn` annotation that specifies the local column that is the foreign key (`EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_ID`) as well as to which column of the foreign table its corresponds (`EMPLOYEE_ID`).

So I am assuming you have `EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_ID` in you GENDER table, which is a foreign key refrring to  primary key of `EMPLOYEE_DETAIL` table and `EMPLOYEE_ID` is the column in `EMPLOYEE_DETAIL` table. Thus, your final mapping will be as below:

```
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_DETAIL_ID",referencedColumnName="EMPLOYEE_ID ")
```

And make sure "gen" is a property in `EmployeeDetailEntity.java` as below:

```
GenderEntity gen;
```